# Can't Install Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8

I do have latest version of Ubuntu , and I would like to remove it to INstall Windows 8.1

but when I begin installing Windows , it tells me can't install in this partition because it's not NTFS or something ... what should I Do please ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Delete partitions and make new ones! it's as simple as that.

`ext4` partitions can't be read by Windows so you'll lose all your data.

Comment: I have gparted , how I can change to NTFS or .. make new one as you said

Comment: @user3091970 make new ones using Windows installer.

Comment: it's not allowing to make new Parition , it's disabled :x

Comment: The `Format` button is disabled, not the `Delete` one ?!

Comment: Format is enabled,delete too , but "New parition" is not

Comment: First `Delete`, then select the unallocated space and `New Partition` will be enabled.

Comment: "Nous n'avons pas pu créer de partition, ni localiser une partition existante"

getting this error when I try to install (on new parition that I made)

Comment: Should I delete them all ? even the System one ? this won't hurt my PC OR SOMETHING ? AND UBUNTU will still run fine ?

Comment: yes but .. I'll have windows or what :x or a PC without operating system :(

Comment: and should I delete all Partitions and create one new ? PLEASE Explain :(

Comment: @user3091970 there is no other way to install Windows. Ubuntu however can be installed later on any partition.

Comment: no chance to install Windows ? 0% ? :x

Comment: or it's possible , don't get you :(